# Regularity of solutions to an integral ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm trying to figure out the regularity for solutions to the following integral equation:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\frac{d}{dt}}u(t,x)&=\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sigma_d\epsilon^{d+2}}}\int_{\mathbb{T}^d}\sin\left(u(t,y)-u(t,x)\right)1_{\{|y-x|\le\epsilon\}}dy, \label{eq:int}\\[10pt]
u|_{t=0}&=u_0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Here $\epsilon>0$ is a parameter and $\mathbb{T}^d$ is the $d-$dimensional torus. One can construct solutions that live in the space $C([0,\infty),L^1(\mathbb{T}^d))$ via a fixed point argument. My question is: are solutions to this equation as good as the initial condition $u_0$ in the spatial domain (i.e. $u_0\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d)\Rightarrow u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d)$)?

My first guess is yes, becuase event if the integral term does not regularize solutions (since there is no derivative on the right hand side as, say, in the heat equation) it doesn't make them worst. I thought of something like an Euler's method to prove it:
$$
u_n(t,x)=u_{n-1}(t,x)+h\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sigma_d\epsilon^{d+2}}}\int_{\mathbb{T}^d}\sin\left(u_{n-1}(t,y)-u_{n-1}(t,x)\right)1_{\{|y-x|\le\epsilon\}}dy. 
$$
Since $u_0$ is smooth in $x$, so is $u_1$ and so on.

Comment: Could be easier to substitute the indicator function $1$ with a smooth one. Is this allowed by the problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi Giorgio. Yes, I can certainly do that. Indicator function for me is just a way to localize interactions. However, it doesn't quite solve the issue.

Comment: With a smooth function instead of the characteristic function, you can formally differentiate under the integral. Maybe you can use this for a fix point argument in a space of smoother functions or the approximation scheme you wrote above.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a fixed point argument, the problem is that you need continuity, say from $C^{2,\alpha}$ to itself and you cannot bound the second derivatives of the integral with the second derivatives of the original function or something like that.